# electron-forge package command hangs on arch: x64, no out folder is generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I'm fairly new to Electron, and I'm running into a problem when I go to `npm run package` my project. It hangs [right there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLLES.png). I've tried everything from `npm cache clear --force` to reinstalling node. I can provide more files and information as needed, but I've included my `package.json` below. Sorry if this is a noob question or the solution is obvious, but I'm not really sure what to do here. I can't even `package` or `make` the default starter project from electron-forge's github repo, I run into the same problem. Thank you for your time.

```js
{
  "name": "nuken",
  "productName": "nuken",
  "version": "8.0.0",
  "description": "nuken is a development environment for web-based applications.",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint src --color"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "nuken Dev Team",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {
            "name": "nuken"
          },
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux"
          ],
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "nuken"
          },
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-appx",
          "config": {
            "packageName": "",
            "name": "nuken"
          },
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "publishers": [
        {
          "config": {
            "repository": {
              "name": "",
              "owner": ""
            }
          },
          "name": "@electron-forge/publisher-github",
          "platforms": "darwin"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.8",
    "abbrev": "^1.1.1",
    "agent-base": "^6.0.2",
    "agentkeepalive": "^4.2.1",
    "aggregate-error": "^3.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "ansi-escapes": "^4.3.2",
    "ansi-regex": "^5.0.1",
    "ansi-styles": "^4.3.0",
    "aproba": "^2.0.0",
    "are-we-there-yet": "^3.0.0",
    "asar": "^3.1.0",
    "asn1": "^0.2.6",
    "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
    "async": "^0.1.22",
    "asynckit": "^0.4.0",
    "at-least-node": "^1.0.0",
    "author-regex": "^1.0.0",
    "available-typed-arrays": "^1.0.5",
    "aws-sign2": "^0.7.0",
    "aws4": "^1.11.0",
    "balanced-match": "^1.0.2",
    "base64-js": "^1.5.1",
    "bcrypt-pbkdf": "^1.0.2",
    "bl": "^4.1.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "boolean": "^3.2.0",
    "brace-expansion": "^1.1.11",
    "braces": "^3.0.2",
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "buffer-alloc": "^1.2.0",
    "buffer-alloc-unsafe": "^1.1.0",
    "buffer-crc32": "^0.2.13",
    "buffer-equal": "^1.0.0",
    "buffer-fill": "^1.0.0",
    "buffer-from": "^1.1.2",
    "cacache": "^15.3.0",
    "cacheable-lookup": "^5.0.4",
    "cacheable-request": "^6.1.0",
    "call-bind": "^1.0.2",
    "caseless": "^0.12.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "chardet": "^0.7.0",
    "chownr": "^2.0.0",
    "chromium-pickle-js": "^0.2.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "clean-stack": "^2.2.0",
    "cli-cursor": "^3.1.0",
    "cli-spinners": "^2.6.1",
    "cli-width": "^3.0.0",
    "clone": "^1.0.4",
    "clone-response": "^1.0.2",
    "code-point-at": "^1.1.0",
    "color-convert": "^2.0.1",
    "color-name": "^1.1.4",
    "color-support": "^1.1.3",
    "colors": "^1.0.3",
    "combined-stream": "^1.0.8",
    "commander": "^4.1.1",
    "compare-version": "^0.1.2",
    "compress-brotli": "^1.3.8",
    "concat-map": "^0.0.1",
    "concat-stream": "^1.6.2",
    "config-chain": "^1.1.13",
    "console-control-strings": "^1.1.0",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "cross-spawn": "^7.0.3",
    "cross-spawn-windows-exe": "^1.2.0",
    "cross-zip": "^4.0.0",
    "cuint": "^0.2.2",
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^4.1.0",
    "dashdash": "^1.14.1",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "decompress-response": "^3.3.0",
    "deep-equal": "^2.0.5",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "defaults": "^1.0.3",
    "defer-to-connect": "^1.1.3",
    "define-lazy-prop": "^2.0.0",
    "define-properties": "^1.1.4",
    "delayed-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "delegates": "^1.0.0",
    "depd": "^1.1.2",
    "detect-libc": "^1.0.3",
    "detect-node": "^2.1.0",
    "dir-compare": "^2.4.0",
    "duplexer3": "^0.1.4",
    "ecc-jsbn": "^0.1.2",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-dl": "^3.3.1",
    "electron-installer-common": "^0.10.3",
    "electron-is-dev": "^0.3.0",
    "electron-notarize": "^1.2.1",
    "electron-prompt": "^1.7.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "emoji-regex": "^8.0.0",
    "encodeurl": "^1.0.2",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "end-of-stream": "^1.4.4",
    "env-paths": "^2.2.1",
    "err-code": "^2.0.3",
    "error-ex": "^1.3.2",
    "es-abstract": "^1.20.1",
    "es-get-iterator": "^1.1.2",
    "es-to-primitive": "^1.2.1",
    "es6-error": "^4.1.1",
    "escalade": "^3.1.1",
    "escape-goat": "^2.1.1",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "execa": "^1.0.0",
    "expand-tilde": "^2.0.2",
    "ext-list": "^2.2.2",
    "ext-name": "^5.0.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.2",
    "external-editor": "^3.1.0",
    "extract-zip": "^2.0.1",
    "extsprintf": "^1.3.0",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
    "fast-glob": "^3.2.11",
    "fast-json-stable-stringify": "^2.1.0",
    "fastq": "^1.13.0",
    "fd-slicer": "^1.1.0",
    "figures": "^3.2.0",
    "filename-reserved-regex": "^2.0.0",
    "filenamify": "^4.3.0",
    "fill-range": "^7.0.1",
    "find-up": "^5.0.0",
    "flora-colossus": "^1.0.1",
    "for-each": "^0.3.3",
    "forever-agent": "^0.6.1",
    "form-data": "^2.3.3",
    "frameless-titlebar": "^2.1.4",
    "fresh": "^0.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "fs-minipass": "^2.1.0",
    "fs.realpath": "^1.0.0",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
    "function.prototype.name": "^1.1.5",
    "functions-have-names": "^1.2.3",
    "galactus": "^0.2.1",
    "gauge": "^4.0.4",
    "get-caller-file": "^2.0.5",
    "get-installed-path": "^2.1.1",
    "get-intrinsic": "^1.1.1",
    "get-package-info": "^1.0.0",
    "get-stream": "^5.2.0",
    "get-symbol-description": "^1.0.0",
    "getpass": "^0.1.7",
    "github-url-to-object": "^4.0.6",
    "glob": "^7.2.2",
    "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
    "global-agent": "^3.0.0",
    "global-modules": "^1.0.0",
    "global-prefix": "^1.0.2",
    "global-tunnel-ng": "^2.7.1",
    "globalthis": "^1.0.3",
    "got": "^12.1.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.10",
    "graceful-readlink": "^1.0.1",
    "har-schema": "^2.0.0",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.5",
    "has": "^1.0.3",
    "has-bigints": "^1.0.2",
    "has-flag": "^4.0.0",
    "has-property-descriptors": "^1.0.0",
    "has-symbols": "^1.0.3",
    "has-tostringtag": "^1.0.0",
    "has-unicode": "^2.0.1",
    "homedir-polyfill": "^1.0.3",
    "hosted-git-info": "^2.8.9",
    "http-cache-semantics": "^4.1.0",
    "http-proxy": "^0.10.0",
    "http-proxy-agent": "^4.0.1",
    "http-signature": "^1.2.0",
    "http2-wrapper": "^1.0.3",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.1",
    "humanize-ms": "^1.2.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.24",
    "ieee754": "^1.2.1",
    "imurmurhash": "^0.1.4",
    "indent-string": "^4.0.0",
    "infer-owner": "^1.0.4",
    "inflight": "^1.0.6",
    "inherits": "^2.0.4",
    "ini": "^1.3.8",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.4",
    "internal-slot": "^1.0.3",
    "ip": "^1.1.8",
    "is-arguments": "^1.1.1",
    "is-arrayish": "^0.2.1",
    "is-bigint": "^1.0.4",
    "is-boolean-object": "^1.1.2",
    "is-callable": "^1.2.4",
    "is-core-module": "^2.9.0",
    "is-date-object": "^1.0.5",
    "is-docker": "^2.2.1",
    "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
    "is-fullwidth-code-point": "^3.0.0",
    "is-glob": "^4.0.3",
    "is-interactive": "^1.0.0",
    "is-lambda": "^1.0.1",
    "is-map": "^2.0.2",
    "is-negative-zero": "^2.0.2",
    "is-number": "^7.0.0",
    "is-number-object": "^1.0.7",
    "is-plain-obj": "^1.1.0",
    "is-regex": "^1.1.4",
    "is-set": "^2.0.2",
    "is-shared-array-buffer": "^1.0.2",
    "is-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "is-string": "^1.0.7",
    "is-symbol": "^1.0.4",
    "is-typed-array": "^1.1.9",
    "is-typedarray": "^1.0.0",
    "is-unicode-supported": "^0.1.0",
    "is-url": "^1.2.4",
    "is-weakmap": "^2.0.1",
    "is-weakref": "^1.0.2",
    "is-weakset": "^2.0.2",
    "is-windows": "^1.0.2",
    "is-wsl": "^2.2.0",
    "isarray": "^0.0.1",
    "isbinaryfile": "^3.0.3",
    "isexe": "^2.0.0",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "js-tokens": "^4.0.0",
    "jsbn": "^0.1.1",
    "json-buffer": "^3.0.0",
    "json-schema": "^0.4.0",
    "json-schema-traverse": "^0.4.1",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "jsonfile": "^6.1.0",
    "jsprim": "^1.4.2",
    "junk": "^3.1.0",
    "keypress": "^0.1.0",
    "keyv": "^3.1.0",
    "load-json-file": "^2.0.0",
    "locate-path": "^6.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash._reinterpolate": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.template": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.templatesettings": "^4.2.0",
    "log-symbols": "^4.1.0",
    "loose-envify": "^1.4.0",
    "lowercase-keys": "^1.0.1",
    "lru-cache": "^6.0.0",
    "lzma-native": "^8.0.6",
    "make-fetch-happen": "^9.1.0",
    "map-age-cleaner": "^0.1.3",
    "matcher": "^3.0.0",
    "mem": "^4.3.0",
    "merge2": "^1.4.1",
    "micromatch": "^4.0.5",
    "mime": "^1.2.6",
    "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "mimic-fn": "^2.1.0",
    "mimic-response": "^1.0.1",
    "minimatch": "^3.1.2",
    "minimist": "^1.2.6",
    "minipass": "^3.1.6",
    "minipass-collect": "^1.0.2",
    "minipass-fetch": "^1.4.1",
    "minipass-flush": "^1.0.5",
    "minipass-pipeline": "^1.2.4",
    "minipass-sized": "^1.0.3",
    "minizlib": "^2.1.2",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
    "modify-filename": "^1.1.0",
    "ms": "^2.0.0",
    "mute-stream": "^0.0.8",
    "ncp": "^0.2.7",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.3",
    "nice-try": "^1.0.5",
    "node-abi": "^3.15.0",
    "node-addon-api": "^3.2.1",
    "node-api-version": "^0.1.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "node-gyp": "^8.4.1",
    "node-gyp-build": "^4.4.0",
    "nopt": "^5.0.0",
    "normalize-package-data": "^2.5.0",
    "normalize-url": "^4.5.1",
    "npm-conf": "^1.1.3",
    "npm-run-path": "^2.0.2",
    "npmlog": "^6.0.2",
    "nugget": "^2.0.2",
    "number-is-nan": "^1.0.1",
    "oauth-sign": "^0.9.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "object-inspect": "^1.12.2",
    "object-is": "^1.1.5",
    "object-keys": "^1.1.1",
    "object.assign": "^4.1.2",
    "once": "^1.4.0",
    "onetime": "^5.1.2",
    "open": "^8.4.0",
    "optimist": "^0.3.7",
    "ora": "^5.4.1",
    "os-tmpdir": "^1.0.2",
    "p-cancelable": "^1.1.0",
    "p-defer": "^1.0.0",
    "p-finally": "^1.0.0",
    "p-is-promise": "^2.1.0",
    "p-limit": "^3.1.0",
    "p-locate": "^5.0.0",
    "p-map": "^4.0.0",
    "p-try": "^2.2.0",
    "parse-author": "^2.0.0",
    "parse-json": "^2.2.0",
    "parse-ms": "^2.1.0",
    "parse-passwd": "^1.0.0",
    "path-exists": "^4.0.0",
    "path-is-absolute": "^1.0.1",
    "path-key": "^3.1.1",
    "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
    "path-type": "^2.0.0",
    "pend": "^1.2.0",
    "performance-now": "^2.1.0",
    "picomatch": "^2.3.1",
    "pify": "^3.0.0",
    "pkg-dir": "^4.2.0",
    "pkginfo": "^0.2.3",
    "plist": "^3.0.5",
    "prepend-http": "^2.0.0",
    "pretty-bytes": "^4.0.2",
    "pretty-ms": "^7.0.1",
    "process-nextick-args": "^2.0.1",
    "progress": "^2.0.3",
    "progress-stream": "^1.2.0",
    "promise-inflight": "^1.0.1",
    "promise-retry": "^2.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "proto-list": "^1.2.4",
    "psl": "^1.8.0",
    "pump": "^3.0.0",
    "punycode": "^2.1.1",
    "pupa": "^2.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.5.3",
    "queue-microtask": "^1.2.3",
    "quick-lru": "^5.1.1",
    "range-parser": "^0.0.4",
    "rcedit": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "read-pkg": "^2.0.0",
    "read-pkg-up": "^2.0.0",
    "readable-stream": "^3.6.0",
    "regexp.prototype.flags": "^1.4.3",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "require-directory": "^2.1.1",
    "resolve": "^1.22.0",
    "resolve-alpn": "^1.2.1",
    "resolve-dir": "^1.0.1",
    "resolve-package": "^1.0.1",
    "responselike": "^1.0.2",
    "restore-cursor": "^3.1.0",
    "retry": "^0.12.0",
    "reusify": "^1.0.4",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "roarr": "^2.15.4",
    "run-async": "^2.4.1",
    "run-parallel": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "safer-buffer": "^2.1.2",
    "semver": "^7.3.7",
    "semver-compare": "^1.0.0",
    "send": "^0.1.0",
    "serialize-error": "^7.0.1",
    "set-blocking": "^2.0.0",
    "shebang-command": "^2.0.0",
    "shebang-regex": "^3.0.0",
    "side-channel": "^1.0.4",
    "signal-exit": "^3.0.7",
    "single-line-log": "^1.1.2",
    "smart-buffer": "^4.2.0",
    "socks": "^2.6.2",
    "socks-proxy-agent": "^6.2.0",
    "sort-keys": "^1.1.2",
    "sort-keys-length": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "spdx-correct": "^3.1.1",
    "spdx-exceptions": "^2.3.0",
    "spdx-expression-parse": "^3.0.1",
    "spdx-license-ids": "^3.0.11",
    "speedometer": "^0.1.4",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "sshpk": "^1.17.0",
    "ssri": "^8.0.1",
    "string_decoder": "^1.3.0",
    "string-width": "^4.2.3",
    "string.prototype.trimend": "^1.0.5",
    "string.prototype.trimstart": "^1.0.5",
    "strip-ansi": "^6.0.1",
    "strip-bom": "^3.0.0",
    "strip-eof": "^1.0.0",
    "strip-outer": "^1.0.1",
    "sudo-prompt": "^9.2.1",
    "sumchecker": "^3.0.1",
    "supports-color": "^7.2.0",
    "supports-preserve-symlinks-flag": "^1.0.0",
    "tar": "^6.1.11",
    "temp": "^0.9.4",
    "throttleit": "^0.0.2",
    "through": "^2.3.8",
    "through2": "^0.2.3",
    "tmp": "^0.0.33",
    "tmp-promise": "^3.0.3",
    "to-readable-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1",
    "tough-cookie": "^2.5.0",
    "tr46": "^0.0.3",
    "trim-repeated": "^1.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "tunnel": "^0.0.6",
    "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
    "tweetnacl": "^0.14.5",
    "type-fest": "^0.21.3",
    "typedarray": "^0.0.6",
    "unbox-primitive": "^1.0.2",
    "underscore": "^1.4.4",
    "unique-filename": "^1.1.1",
    "unique-slug": "^2.0.2",
    "universalify": "^2.0.0",
    "unused-filename": "^2.1.0",
    "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1",
    "uri-js": "^4.4.1",
    "url-parse-lax": "^3.0.0",
    "username": "^5.1.0",
    "util-deprecate": "^1.0.2",
    "utile": "^0.1.7",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "validate-npm-package-license": "^3.0.4",
    "verror": "^1.10.0",
    "wcwidth": "^1.0.1",
    "webidl-conversions": "^3.0.1",
    "whatwg-url": "^5.0.0",
    "which": "^2.0.2",
    "which-boxed-primitive": "^1.0.2",
    "which-collection": "^1.0.1",
    "which-typed-array": "^1.1.8",
    "wide-align": "^1.1.5",
    "word-wrap": "^1.2.3",
    "wordwrap": "^0.0.3",
    "wrap-ansi": "^7.0.0",
    "wrappy": "^1.0.2",
    "xmlbuilder": "^9.0.7",
    "xtend": "^2.1.2",
    "yallist": "^4.0.0",
    "yargs-parser": "^20.2.9",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19",
    "yarn-or-npm": "^3.0.1",
    "yauzl": "^2.10.0",
    "yocto-queue": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-appx": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/publisher-github": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "coffee-script": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^18.2.3",
    "eslint": "^3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7"
  }
}
```